# How do I obtain the localization attribute labels for an model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, localization

Lets say I have a typical 'User' model with a 'first_name' field.  I set up localization like this to handle a human readable label:

```
en:
  activerecord:
    attributes:
      user:
        first_name: "First Name"
```

For a given @user object can I access that "First Name" label for use in a view etc.?

I am sure this is possible - I can't seem to find this anywhere easily.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Model attributes are related to... **models**, not **instances**.

For an `User` model you'd write

```rb
User.human_attribute_name(:first_name)
```

If you're really want to get the value from an user instance, then

```rb
@user.class.human_attribute_name(:first_name)
```

Your almost exact example is documented here
https://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#translations-for-active-record-models

Comment: Yup - your first example was exactly what I was looking for.  I know that I read that page 100% and missed that 'Model.human_attribute_name(attribute)' completely.  The second part works too but when I wrote this post I wasn't thinking straight about model vs instance.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you need that `@user` object because for all user object that `first_name` label is same.

Just try:

```
 I18n.t "activerecord.attributes.user.first_name"
```

More deatils [here](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#the-public-i18n-api).

**Update**

Answer by `@colinux` is most elegant. `User.human_attribute_name(:first_name)` use that one.